# Problema com meu jogo da Forca - Python

Tags: python

```
print("*** Jogo da forca ***\n")
print("*** Feito por Igor! ***\n")
palavraSecreta = input("Entre com a palavra secreta: ")
letrasDescobertas = []
percorrer = 0
contador = int(input("Entre com o número de chances: "))

for i in range(len(palavraSecreta)):
    if palavraSecreta[i] == " ":
        letrasDescobertas.append(" ")
    else:
        letrasDescobertas.append("-")
print("".join(letrasDescobertas))

acertou = False

while acertou is False:
    letra = input("Digite a letra de seu chute: ")

    for i in range(len(palavraSecreta)):
        if letra == palavraSecreta[i]:
            letrasDescobertas[i] = letra
            print("".join(letrasDescobertas))

    if letra not in palavraSecreta:
        percorrer += 1
        print("Chances restantes:", contador - percorrer)
        if percorrer == contador:
            print("Você perdeu!")
            break

    if "-" not in letrasDescobertas:
        print("Você ganhou com %d erros!" % percorrer)
        acertou = True
```

Minha charada é pao: Se eu digitar d, f, g. Deveria mostrar as letras erradas assim: d, f, g. Porém a saída que tenho com esse código que fiz é somente a última letra digitada. Por exemplo: Digitei d, vai aparecer d. Digitei f, vai aparecer somente o f, ao invés de d, f. Como arrumar? Obrigado

Comment: Poderia disponibilizar o código para fica mais fácil?

Comment: Pronto, o código está acima (a indentação ficou um pouco errada aqui no site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, agora eu realmente entendi qual era o problema e agora editei para corrigir.

**Segue o código:**

Preste atenção no que eu fiz, por que nem eu sei direito o que realmente fiz. 
Mas o resultado é perfeito.

```
print("*** Jogo da forca ***\n")
palavraSecreta = input("Entre com a palavra secreta: ")
palavraSecreta = palavraSecreta.split(' ')

letrasDescobertas = []

for i in palavraSecreta:
    for b in i:
        letrasDescobertas.append('_')
    letrasDescobertas.append(' ') # A cada intervalo é adicionado um espaço

acertou = False

while acertou is False:
    letra = input("Digite a letra de seu chute: ")
    x = 0
    for i in palavraSecreta: # Não precisa por zero no começo, o padrão é sempre zero

        for b in i:
            if letra == b:
                if letrasDescobertas[x] == ' ': # É preciso incrementa aqui por que senão o espaço vai ser substituído 
                    x += 1
                letrasDescobertas[x] = letra
            x += 1
        x += 1 # Quando ele muda para o outra palavra é necessário incrementar +1

    print(''.join(letrasDescobertas))


    if '_' not in letrasDescobertas: # Mudei isso aqui também, ficou melhor.
        acertou = True

print("Parabéns!")
```

**Saída:**

```
>>> *** Jogo da forca ***
>>> 
>>> Entre com a palavra secreta: um teste
>>> Digite a letra de seu chute: u
>>> u_ _____ 
>>> Digite a letra de seu chute: m
>>> um _____ 
>>> Digite a letra de seu chute: t
>>> um t__t_ 
>>> Digite a letra de seu chute: e
>>> um te_te 
>>> Digite a letra de seu chute: s
>>> um teste 
>>> Parabéns!
```

**Letras já usadas:**

Adicione isso após o `while acertou is False:`

```
while acertou is False:
    letra = input("Digite a letra de seu chute: ")

    if letra in usadas: # Adicione isto
          print('\nVocê já falou essa letra!\n') # Adicione isto
          continue # Adicione isto

    usadas.append(letra) # Adicione isto
```

**Saída:**

```
>>> *** Jogo da forca ***
>>> 
>>> Entre com a palavra secreta: antony
>>> Digite a letra de seu chute: a
>>> a_____
>>> Digite a letra de seu chute: a
>>> 
>>> Você já falou essa letra!
>>> 
>>> Digite a letra de seu chute:
```

Comment: Então cara, o problema é que eu queria que tivesse o traçinho ou a underline, pra mostrar para o jogador o numero de palavras. Mas o problema é que quando a palavra tem espaço, o programa contabiliza o espaço como letra, então ele adiciona um "-" para o espaço. Deu pra entender?

Comment: Pronto, editei, eu não havia entendido direito.

Comment: Nossa, me confundi todo com esse código... O que você fez ali? Hahaha

Comment: Consegui fazer de um jeito mais simplificado :D, olhei seu código e tive a ideia, e deu certo xD. Dá uma olhada lá, modifiquei o código meu acima

Comment: Então, eu dei mais uma implementada no meu código. Agora gostaria que tivesse uma lista que salvasse todas as letras erradas e printasse na tela. Quase consegui fazer isso, porém essa lista só mostra o último conteúdo da lista, ao invés de mostrar a lista toda. Será que poderia me ajudar? Código acima

Comment: No caso seriam letras que já foram usadas, correto? Se for isso, atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Não deu certo aqui não Antony. E a intenção era não só mostrar a msg, e sim as letras que já foram usadas. Disponibilizei meu código todo acima

Comment: Pra isso é só digitar print(usadas), bom aqui tá tranquilo mano.

Comment: Será que tem como disponibilizar seu código todo por favor? Obrigado mano!

Comment: O tópico vai ficar muito longo, é só substituir a ultima parte que eu citei, e colocar `usadas = []` acima do While, não mais que isso.

Comment: Deu certo aqui irmão! Agora uma última dúvida se puder me ajudar. Porque quando coloco o "usadas = []" aqui, o código não funciona?: while acertou is False:
    letra = input("Digite a letra de seu chute: ")
    usadas = []

Comment: E quando coloco o usadas acima do While acertou is false o código funciona? Fiquei em dúvida

Comment: Por que `usadas=[]`estará sempre resetando quando o while voltar para o inicio  e acima do While ela irá armazenar os dados sem resetar, entendeu?

Comment: Puts cara, verdade hahaha. Entendi, desculpa pela pergunta noob, e muito obrigado pela ajuda, muito obrigado mesmo! :)

Comment: Nada, ninguém nasce sabendo, é vivendo e aprendendo. :)